# How to perform min and max validation in angular reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have the following code:

```
    constructor() { 
this.feedbackForm = new FormGroup({
  suggestedAScore: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/),Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5), Validators.minLength(5)]),
  minScore: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/),Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1),Validators.maxLength(1)]),
  maxScore: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]+$/),Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1),Validators.maxLength(1)])
});
this.feedbackForm.setValidators(this.minMaxValidator());
 }




public minMaxValidator() : ValidatorFn{
return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors => {
  const min = group.controls['minScore'];
  const max = group.controls['maxScore'];
  var changedValue;
  if (min.value && max.value) {
    if (this.prevMinVal && (this.prevMinVal === min.value)) {
      changedValue = max;
      this.errorMessage = 'Max value should be greater than Min value';
    } else {
      changedValue = min;
      this.errorMessage = 'Min value should be lesser than Max value';
    }
    this.prevMinVal = min.value;
    if (min.value >=  max.value) {
      changedValue.setErrors({notEquivalent: true});
    } else {
      min.setErrors(null);
      max.setErrors(null);
    }
  };
 // this.isFeedbackFormValid();
    return;
 }
 };
```

Here with this code when I enter max value less than min value the error is shown at min not at max.My question is how to highlight the input that entered is wrong.Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Comment: If possible then provide stackblitz demo! where I/we can reproduce an issue/current behaviour

Comment: You can write a custom directive to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have to create custom Validator like this:

```
const RangeValidator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
  const start = fg.get('min').value;
  const end = fg.get('max').value;
  return start !== null && end !== null && parseFloat(start) < parseFloat(end)
    ? null
    : { range: true };
};
```

In your ts file while creating the form you have to provide Validation on a full form so you get both input value changes

```
this.formbuilder.group({
      min: [null, [//Your Validation for number/decimal]],
      max: [null, [//Your Validation for number/decimal]]
}, { validator: RangeValidator }))
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you creating your own logic of min and max `validators` when `angular` provides `min` and `max` native validation.

When you set validation in your `FormControl` so you can just a single condition in your
`component.hmtl` like this

```
 <mat-error *ngIf="feedbackForm.controls.minScore.hasError('minlength')">
    Your error message here. 
  </mat-error>
```

I just showed you an example that how can you show errors conditionally using `validators`.

You can make a css class that make your input red like this

```
.error{border-color : red}
```

And inside your html on your input you can do like this

```
<input type="text" formControl="minScore" [ngClass]="{'error' :(feedbackForm.get('minScore').touched || feedbackForm.get('minScore').dirty) && !feedbackForm.get('minScore').valid }">
```

Comment: material yet included the "border-color". If you not use material input else a "normal" input, Angular yet included a class "ng-invalid", so, use this class and remove the [ngClass], see https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes